# Dynamic formation of variable name in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

The code below dynamically concatenates keys to an existing array `$options_pool`. So the final form should be: `$options_pool[ $base_key ][ $first_key ][ $second_key ]`... This is so I can dynamically assign a value to the elements of the array `$options_pool` which is multidimensional.

```
foreach( $this->post_vars as $name => $value ) {
    //Look for $name key in array $options_pool if it exists.
    //Use multi_array_key_exists() to handle the task
    //It should return something like "fruit:mango:apple_mango"
    //Then dynamically call $options_pool based on the data. Like so: $options_pool[ 'fruit' ][ 'mango' ][ 'apple_mango' ] = $value;
    $match_key = multi_array_key_exists( $name, $options_pool );
    $option_keys = explode( ':', $match_key );
    $option_keys_length = count( $option_keys );
    $option_name_array = array(); 
    if( 0 < $option_keys_length ) {
     for( $c = $option_keys_length; $c > 0; $c-- ) {
         $sub_keys = '$options_pool';
         for( $c_sub = 0; $c_sub < $c ; $c_sub++ ) {
             $sub_keys .= '[ $option_keys[ '.  $c_sub . ' ] ]';  
         }
         $option_name_array[] = $sub_keys;
     } 
     foreach( $option_name_array as $f_var_name ) {
          //the following line should equal to: $options_pool[ 'fruit' ][ 'mango' ][ 'apple_mango' ] = $value;
          $f_var_name = $value;  
       }
    }
}

//The $options_pool array
$options_pool = array( 'car' => '', 'animals' => '', 'fruit' => array( 'mango' => array( 'apple_mango' => '' ));
```

I think the logic is correct except that this portion of the code:

```
foreach( $option_name_array as $f_var_name ) {
    $f_var_name = $value; //particularly this line 
}
```

doesn't work? I've tested printing the value of `$f_var_name` and the result is correct but it doesn't really call the array?

Comment: `foreach` constructs in PHP work on copies of the supplied array. [Learn more.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: So what could be the possible workaround for this? I just updated my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is incorrect, you are right.
The variable name will *always* be `$options_pool`.
You can pass the keys as `explode(':', $name)` and later assign them.

By the way, your code at

```
 foreach( $option_keys as $option_keys_value ) {
      $option_key_names[] = $option_keys_value;
 }
```

Do you realize that it just copies `$option_keys` as `$option_key_names` *just* as if you had written `$option_key_names = $option_keys;` (in this code) ?

Maybe with a stack you could do this iteratively but with recursion it is just more natural, as you see here

```
function getVariableToWrite(&$reference, $nested_opts, $write) {
    if(empty($nested_ops)) // Base case
        return $reference = write;
    if(isset($reference[array_shift($nested_ops)]))
        return getVariableToWrite($reference, $nested_ops, $write);
    throw new Exception("The key does not exist..");
}
```

And then just

```
foreach( $this->post_vars as $name => $value ) {
    // Your work over here until...
    $match_key = "fruit:mango:apple_mango";
    $option_keys = explode( ':', $match_key );

    getVariableToWrite($options_pool, $option_keys, $value);
}
```

Will this do the work?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will need to go back to this as sson I get a free time.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. The `$match_key` var already contains the keys to write so you don't have to do that. I have updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Joann I updated the answer. Yes, I did not know exactly what you did, with that in mind, will this do the trick? :)

Comment: I haven't used array_shift yet but I think your solution isn't right. Your function always reads/writes `$options_pool` in a singular form and not multidimensional? So what it does is it only evaluates `$options_pool[ $option_keys[ $x ] ]` recursively which is not what I intend to do.

Comment: No, it wil take the reference of ($options_pool[$key]) in the next call, so you will efectively end up with a `$options_pool[$key1][$key2][$key3]` access. It would be something like (this is forbidden syntax in PHP) `( ( ($options_pool[$key1]) [$key2]) [$key3] )`, which is what you want. i.e., if you do `$test = &$options[$key1]` then `$test[$key2] === $options[$key1][$key2]`

Answer (score 1):

In your `foreach`, you need to pass the value by reference, so you can edit it.

```
foreach( $option_name_array as &$f_var_name ){
  $f_var_name = $value;  
}
```

Comment: This didn't work because var `$option_name_array` isn't the array that's going to be manipulated. It only contains vars that represent the name( with varying length of concatenated keys ) of the array to be manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
foreach( $option_name_array as $key => $f_var_name ) {
    $option_name_array[$key] = $value; //particularly this line 
}
```